# If $xy+xz+yz=3$ so $\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(x^2y+x^2z+2\sqrt{xyz(x^3+3x)}\right)\geq2xyz\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2+2)$

Tags: inequality, radicals, functional-inequalities, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

Prove that for any set of three positive real $x, y, z$ such that $xy+yz+zx=3$

$x^2(y+z)+y^2(x+z)+z^2(x+y)+2\sqrt {xyz}\left(\sqrt{x^3+3x}+\sqrt{y^3+3x}+\sqrt{z^3+3x}\right)\ge$
$\ge 2xyz(x^2+y^2+z^2+6)$

Reasoning I know that the minimum value is with $x=y=z$ 
We have to find an equation equivalent to the date where we subtract and divide by xyz and don't appear other variables.

Comment: What is an original inequality?

Comment: I haven't understand

Comment: How you got this inequality?

Comment: Exercising at school for math competition, my teacher has proposed it, but I can't figure out how to move on.

Comment: I think it's from past math games

Comment: What is your trying?

Comment: I know that the minimum value is with x=y=z. I've done a problem like this recently and I risolved it finding an equation in wich had te maximium result for the minimum number assumed by variables. In this equation the minimum is x=y=z=1 so I want to find something equivalent in wich compares only xyz or (x+y+z)

Answer (score 4):

We need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(x^2y+x^2z+2\sqrt{xyz}\sqrt{x(x+y)(x+z)}\right)\geq2xyz(x+y+z)^2.$$
Now, by C-S $$\sqrt{x(x+y)(x+z)}\geq\sqrt{x}(x+\sqrt{yz})=\sqrt{x^3}+\sqrt{xyz}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^2y+x^2z+2\sqrt{x^4yz}+2xyz)\geq2xyz(x+y+z)^2$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}xy\sum_{cyc}(x^2y+x^2z+2\sqrt{x^4yz}+2xyz)\geq6xyz(x+y+z)^2$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(x^3y^2+x^3z^2+2x^3yz+8x^2y^2z+2\sqrt{x^6y^3z}+2\sqrt{x^6z^3y}+2\sqrt{x^4y^3z^3}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq\sum_{cyc}(6x^3yz+12x^2y^2z)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(x^3y^2+x^3z^2-4x^3yz-4x^2y^2z+2\sqrt{x^6y^3z}+2\sqrt{x^6z^3y}+2\sqrt{x^4y^3z^3}\right)\geq0.$$
Now, $$\sum_{cyc}\left(\sqrt{x^6y^3z}+\sqrt{x^6z^3y}-2x^3yz\right)=\sum_{cyc}x^3\sqrt{yz}(\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{z})^2\geq0.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(x^3y^2+x^3z^2-4x^2y^2z+2\sqrt{x^4y^3z^3}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}z^2\left(x^3+y^3-2x^2y-2xy^2+2\sqrt{x^3y^3}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(x^3-2\sqrt{x^3y^3}+y^3-2(x^2y+xy^2-2\sqrt{x^3y^3})\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}z^2(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2((x+\sqrt{xy}+y)^2-2xy)\geq0,$$
which is obvious.

Done!

Comment: Sorry, what mean $C-S$ ?

Comment: @Alice333 It's Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

Comment: Ah ok, now is clear. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

We need to prove that 
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}xy\sum_{cyc}(x^2y+x^2z)+2\sum\limits_{cyc}xy\sum\limits_{cyc}x\sqrt{yz(x+y)(x+z)}\geq6xyz(x+y+z)^2.$$
Since by C-S $\sqrt{(x+y)(x+z)}\geq x+\sqrt{yz}$, it remains to prove that
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}xy\sum_{cyc}(x^2y+x^2z)+2\sum\limits_{cyc}xy\sum\limits_{cyc}x\sqrt{yz}(x+\sqrt{yz})\geq6xyz(x+y+z)^2$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(x^3y^2+x^3z^2-4x^3yz-4x^2y^2z+2x^3y\sqrt{yz}+2x^3z\sqrt{yz}+2x^2\sqrt{y^3z^3}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(x^6y^4+x^6z^4-4x^6y^2z^2-4x^4y^4z^2+2x^6y^3z+2x^6z^3y+2x^4y^3z^3\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(x^6y^4+x^6z^4-x^6y^3z-x^6z^3y\right)+2\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(x^6y^3z+x^6z^3y-2x^6y^2z^2\right)+$$
$$+\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(x^6y^3z+x^6z^3y-2x^4y^4z^2\right)-\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(2x^4y^4z^2-2x^4y^3z^3\right)\geq0.$$
Since $\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(x^6y^3z+x^6z^3y-2x^6y^2z^2\right)$ and $\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(x^6y^3z+x^6z^3y-2x^4y^4z^2\right)\geq0$,

it remains to prove that
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(x^6y^4+x^6z^4-x^6y^3z-x^6z^3y\right)+\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(x^6y^3z+x^6z^3y-2x^6y^2z^2\right)-$$
$$-\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(2x^4y^4z^2-2x^4y^3z^3\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}z^6(x-y)^2(x^2+xy+y^2)+\sum\limits_{cyc}z^6xy(x-y)^2-x^2y^2z^2\sum\limits_{cyc}z^2(x-y)^2\geq0$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}z^4(x-y)^2(z^2(x+y)^2-x^2y^2)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}z^4(x-y)^2(xz+yz-xy)\geq0.$$
Let $x\geq y\geq z$.

Hence, $(x-z)^2\geq(x-y)^2$, $xy+yz-xz\geq0$ and $xy+xz-yz\geq0$.

Thus,
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}z^4(x-y)^2(xz+yz-xy)\geq$$
$$\geq z^4(x-y)^2(xz+yz-xy)+y^4(x-z)^2(xy+yz-xz)\geq$$
$$\geq z^4(x-y)^2(xz-xy)+y^4(x-y)^2(xy-xz)=$$
$$=x(x-y)^2(y-z)^2(y+z)(y^2+z^2)\geq0$$
Done!