# Inequality very very long

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

> Show that for any positive real numbers   $x$, $y$, $z$ such that $xy + yz + zx = 3$,  we have that:
>   $$x^2(y+z)+y^2(z+x)+z^2(x+y)+2\sqrt{xyz}\left(\sqrt{x^3+3x}+\sqrt{y^3+3y}+\sqrt{z^3+3z}\right) \ge 2xyz\left(x^2+y^2+z^2+6\right)$$

Comment: The same question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052655/if-xyxzyz-3-so-sum-limits-cyc-leftx2yx2z2-sqrtxyzx33x-right).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $xy+xz+yz=3$ so $\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(x^2y+x^2z+2\sqrt{xyz(x^3+3x)}\right)\geq2xyz\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2+2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052655/if-xyxzyz-3-so-sum-limits-cyc-leftx2yx2z2-sqrtxyzx33x-right)